# Detect language of text files

Tags: language

I need an installable/portable/cli software or a tool for Windows that can detect the language of multiple text files, not just strings. Free or paid does not matter.

Sort of like what Google Translate is doing when you paste some text strings, it will auto-detect the language.

I am talking about human languages, not programming.

Comment: Please provide more information about your requirements - is a cloud-based solution acceptable, or must it be installable on the computer? What is your budget? What sort of "text files" (plain text or from a word processor)?

Comment: Text files as in txt

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica you can identify text in several languages. Translation of sentences is also possible using `TextTranslation`.

You can try this by making a free cloud account at the [Wolfram cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/). Files can be read in and analyzed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it able to process multiple files in bulk? Please specify how to do this with the software.

Comment: You can drop a line to their support. As this is a general purpose platform for STEM fields, a bit of programming will be involved. But the answer is that it can.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Python module [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect). It supports 55 languages out of the box. As an example (from the project's README file):

```
>>> from langdetect import detect
>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'
>>> detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
'de'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fasttext by Facebook supports 176 languages: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html